# Ubuntu 20.04 Freezes During Gaming (also some packages can't upgrade)

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, mesa

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

I noticed that whenever I play a game, like Hitman 2 using proton or something, it will freeze after 30mins to 1hr. This never happened on 18.04 LTS.

I noticed packages were not upgradable including libsane1, libsane-common and seem to be stuck in the 18.04 LTS versions. (see screenshots below) If I try to update it, it wants to remove ubuntu-desktop and other ubuntu core packages.

I also noticed that libgl1-mesa-glx (and other libraries that I installed to play games) were still on 20.2.1~kisak1~b which according to this is a bionic 18.04 LTS release. [https://launchpad.net/~kisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa/+build/20149684](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa/+build/20149684)

I suspect some packages were not upgraded to 20.04 LTS during the upgrade and I am not sure how to fix it.

[image: libsane1 and libsane-common are still in 18.04 LTS versions]

[image: I can't upgrade without removing core ubuntu packages]

[image: libgl1-mesa-glx is still on 18.04 LTS version and says it's up to date]

here is my journalctl -b -e output

```
Nov 05 18:28:43 hackintosh tracker-store[3289]: OK
Nov 05 18:28:43 hackintosh systemd[1677]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2502]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_>
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2502]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_>
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2488]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_>
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2488]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_>
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2502]: Can't set a parent on widget which >
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2488]: Can't set a parent on widget which >
Nov 05 18:28:56 hackintosh systemd-resolved[912]: Server returned error NXDOMAI>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh dbus-daemon[1720]: [session uid=1000 pid=1720] Activ>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Created slice apps.slice.
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh dbus-daemon[1720]: [session uid=1000 pid=1720] Succe>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh gnome-terminal-server[3781]: Fontconfig warning: "/e>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh gnome-terminal-server[3781]: Fontconfig warning: "/e>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Started VTE child process 3789 launch>
Nov 05 18:29:27 hackintosh systemd-resolved[912]: Server returned error NXDOMAI>
Nov 05 18:29:29 hackintosh sudo[3823]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/>
Nov 05 18:29:31 hackintosh sudo[3823]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/>
Nov 05 18:29:31 hackintosh sudo[3823]:     cley : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/cley ; >
Nov 05 18:29:31 hackintosh sudo[3823]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened f>
lines 979-1001/1001 (END)
Nov 05 18:28:43 hackintosh tracker-store[3289]: OK
Nov 05 18:28:43 hackintosh systemd[1677]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2502]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2502]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2488]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2488]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2502]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Nov 05 18:28:53 hackintosh nm-applet[2488]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Nov 05 18:28:56 hackintosh systemd-resolved[912]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh dbus-daemon[1720]: [session uid=1000 pid=1720] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.118' (uid=1000 pid=3778 >
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Created slice apps.slice.
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh dbus-daemon[1720]: [session uid=1000 pid=1720] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh gnome-terminal-server[3781]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-ttf-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 61: Having multiple values in  isn't supported and may not work as ex>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh gnome-terminal-server[3781]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-ttf-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 96: Having multiple values in  isn't supported and may not work as ex>
Nov 05 18:29:11 hackintosh systemd[1677]: Started VTE child process 3789 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 3781.
Nov 05 18:29:27 hackintosh systemd-resolved[912]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 05 18:29:29 hackintosh sudo[3823]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Nov 05 18:29:31 hackintosh sudo[3823]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Nov 05 18:29:31 hackintosh sudo[3823]:     cley : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/cley ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -b -e
Nov 05 18:29:31 hackintosh sudo[3823]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

***EDIT

I noticed that my distro upgrade might be broken
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my apt.log

```
Log time: 2020-11-05 18:37:31.210246
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libsensors-config:amd64  1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @in uN Ib >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 
  Considering libsensors4:amd64 6 as a solution to libsensors-config:amd64 0
  Holding Back libsensors-config:amd64 rather than change libsensors4:amd64
Investigating (1) libsensors5:amd64  1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 
  Considering libsensors-config:amd64 0 as a solution to libsensors5:amd64 0
  Holding Back libsensors5:amd64 rather than change libsensors-config:amd64
Investigating (2) libsnmp35:amd64  5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64  (>= 1:3.5.0)
  Considering libsensors5:amd64 0 as a solution to libsnmp35:amd64 3
  Holding Back libsnmp35:amd64 rather than change libsensors5:amd64
Investigating (3) libsane:amd64  1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsane:amd64 Depends on libsnmp35:amd64  (>= 5.8+dfsg)
  Considering libsnmp35:amd64 3 as a solution to libsane:amd64 10
  Holding Back libsane:amd64 rather than change libsnmp35:amd64
Investigating (3) sane-utils:amd64  1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @un uN Ib >
Broken sane-utils:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.27)
  Considering libsane:amd64 10 as a solution to sane-utils:amd64 3
  Holding Back sane-utils:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (3) libsane1:amd64  1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2 @ii umU NPb Ib >
Broken libsane1:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2)
  Considering libsane:amd64 10 as a solution to libsane1:amd64 0
  Removing libsane1:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (4) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 10 as a solution to colord:amd64 42
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (5) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 42 as a solution to colord:amd64 42
  Removing colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (6) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 42 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 54
  Added colord:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-control-center:amd64 via keep of colord:amd64
Investigating (6) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 42 as a solution to colord:amd64 54
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (7) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 54 as a solution to colord:amd64 54
  Removing colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (8) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 54 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 54
  Removing gnome-control-center:amd64 rather than change colord:amd64
Investigating (8) ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 54 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1
  Removing ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 rather than change gnome-control-center:amd64
Investigating (8) ubuntu-desktop:amd64 
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 54 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 0
  Removing ubuntu-desktop:amd64 rather than change gnome-control-center:amd64
Done
ERROR:root:Package brscan4 has no priority set
ERROR:root:Package mfcj480dwlpr:i386 has no priority set
ERROR:root:Package minecraft-launcher has no priority set
ERROR:root:NvidiaDetection returned a error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'server'
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) ubuntu-desktop:amd64 
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 7 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Added gnome-control-center:amd64 to the remove list
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Added ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing ubuntu-desktop:amd64 via keep of gnome-control-center:amd64
  Fixing ubuntu-desktop:amd64 via keep of ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64
Investigating (0) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 5 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 7
  Added colord:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-control-center:amd64 via keep of colord:amd64
Investigating (0) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 0 as a solution to colord:amd64 5
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (1) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 0 as a solution to colord:amd64 5
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (2) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 0 as a solution to colord:amd64 5
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (3) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 5 as a solution to colord:amd64 5
  Removing colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (4) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 5 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 7
  Added colord:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-control-center:amd64 via keep of colord:amd64
Investigating (4) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 5 as a solution to colord:amd64 7
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (5) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 7 as a solution to colord:amd64 7
  Removing colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (6) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 7 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 7
  Removing gnome-control-center:amd64 rather than change colord:amd64
Investigating (6) ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 7 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1
  Removing ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 rather than change gnome-control-center:amd64
Investigating (7) ubuntu-desktop:amd64 
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 7 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Added gnome-control-center:amd64 to the remove list
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 7 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Added ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing ubuntu-desktop:amd64 via keep of gnome-control-center:amd64
  Fixing ubuntu-desktop:amd64 via keep of ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64
Investigating (7) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 7 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 10000
  Added colord:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-control-center:amd64 via keep of colord:amd64
Investigating (7) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 7 as a solution to colord:amd64 10000
  Added libsane:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing colord:amd64 via keep of libsane:amd64
Investigating (8) colord:amd64 
Broken colord:amd64 Depends on libsane:amd64  (>= 1.0.24)
  Considering libsane:amd64 10000 as a solution to colord:amd64 10000
  Removing colord:amd64 rather than change libsane:amd64
Investigating (9) gnome-control-center:amd64 
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on colord:amd64  (>= 0.1.30)
  Considering colord:amd64 10000 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 10000
  Removing gnome-control-center:amd64 rather than change colord:amd64
Investigating (9) ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 
Broken ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 Depends on gnome-control-center:amd64 
  Considering gnome-control-center:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000
  Removing ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 rather than change gnome-control-center:amd64
Done
ERROR:root:failed to mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for install (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was the mesa gl library that didn't get updated with 18.04 LTS.

As suggested by this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1903236

I ran this and it fixed the dependencies:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt upgrade

Thanks kisak for the fix!